# how to simplify this database update query (php)

Tags: php, simplify

How could I simplify this update instruction? Whenever a client buys an item it will update the sales with 1.

```
$this->db->query('SELECT amount FROM shop_items WHERE itemid='.$itemid.'');   
$new_amount = $item->amount+1;
    if(!$this->db->query('UPDATE shop_items SET amount='.$new_amount.' WHERE itemid='.$itemid.'')):
    return false;
    endif;
```

Can't I make it more simple so there are less lines, for example:

```
if(!$this->db->query('UPDATE shop_items SET amount=_current_value_+1 WHERE itemid='.$itemid.'')):
return false;
endif;
```

is this possible? if not thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using the following SQL query :

```
update shop_items
set amount = amount + 1
where itemid = 123
```

Basically, in just one SQL query, you set the `amount` to the previous value it had, plus one.

No need for two queries ;-)

Integrating this in your PHP code should give you something that looks like this :

```
if (!$this->db->query('UPDATE shop_items SET amount=amount+1 WHERE itemid='.$itemid.'')) :
    return false;
endif;
```

Note : I just replaced your `_current_value_` by the name of the field that you're working on : `amount`.